# Does the CPU of your Macbook Pro overheat when gaming using a Thunderbolt external GPU?

Tags: graphics, gpu, games

Does the CPU of your Macbook Pro overheat when gaming using a Thunderbolt external GPU ? 
Any feedback from fellow gamers using an external GPU ? Thanks !

Comment: If your CPU were to overheat, it would a) throttle back, and/or b) thermal shutdown.   The question, as written is much too broad.

Answer (score 1):

No, the CPU does not overheat.

There's no extra CPU-load from the fact that you're using an external GPU compared to an internal GPU.

In addition your CPU cannot overheat in a functioning MacBook Pro. The system will use the fans to cool down the CPU. In the event the fans are not functioning (i.e. broken hardware), the MacBook Pro would simply turn off instead of overheating.

Comment: Hi and thanks for getting back to me. Also to reply @Allan, by overheating I meant heat too much for the hardware enclosure or body of the Mac to the point that it could melt connections or components inside for example ? I realise the Mac would auto shut down if it was too much heating though.

Comment: As an example I'll take my actual Mac that uses the IntelHD 3000 "gpu". Yes it's not the best for gaming and I'm not a serious gamer these days. Still I noticed interesting stuff.

Comment: For example I can play some FPS games just fine, granted not the latest but the ones that came out when I bought my Mac ran fine, however, at the time Starcraft 2 came out a year or 2 before, and the sheer number of units running around really brought my CPU to its knees. You could see that it was the number of units that affected that since with few units at my base for example it was running fine (all on low settings of course). Ok maybe it was also on its knees since with the Intel HD3000 the CPU is also the GPU and I'm not an expert, just investigating.

Comment: There's absolutely no risk of your Mac overheating so that it melts connections or internal component. No risk at all.

Comment: @MFJC - see this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295253/119271

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I'm familiar with thermal safeties on processors as I had a computer shutdown many times on Linux when I was a kid because the fan (as I later found out) was full of thin sand dust. In this case I was more wondering if the external GPU would put additional strain on the internal CPU since the external GPU would boost the computer's performances like an energy drink so to speak, unlocking new levels of performance.

Comment: The answer is still no.

Answer (score 0):

It *shouldn't,* because your eGPU is handling the intensive stuff.