# Is there such a thing as unsafe cpu levels on mac?

Tags: macos, hardware, cpu, resources

Background: The process `com.docker.hyperkit` has consistently been using between 100% and 200% cpu on my mac (which has 2 physical, and (in total) 4 virtual cores).

Question: is there such a thing as unsafe CPU levels (as displayed in the activity monitor) on a mac? If so, at what levels should I get worried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your CPU will thermally throttle itself if it becomes too hot.  If it goes beyond its thermal limit, it will shut itself off.

The only thing you actually have to worry about is reduced performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not an expert here, but I am assuming you are implicitly addressing the risk of killing the CPU during one of these sessions. Would higher avg load over a long timespan not reduce the life of the CPU?

Comment: That’s been engineered in. Obviously, if you run your CPU at 100% all the time, it will shorten its life, but we’re measuring CPU life around the decade mark. Even at full capacity, it will be obsolete before it’s toast

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295250/can-running-yes-dev-null-harm-a-mac/295253#295253

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarifications!